# How to import project specific go packages while maintaining a separate location for go packages that are common to totally different projects?

Tags: go, build, compilation, package

So I was developing a go application for the very first time. I came to know that there are two variables GOROOT and GOPATH which are used to maintain go packages. What I understand till now, is that GOROOT is for the go binary files and GOPATH is mainly for storing library and helper packages that is needed for projects.

Here is my current project structure -

```
/Users/john/work/project-mars
/Users/john/work/project-mars/main.go
/Users/john/work/project-mars/helper
/Users/john/work/project-mars/helper/helper.go
```

Content of main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "helper"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Content of helper.go

```
package helper

import (
    "fmt"
)

func SayWorld(){
    fmt.Println("World")
}
```

And the go variables are -

```
GOROOT = /Users/john/apps/go
GOPATH = /Users/john/apps/go-packages
```

**Problem:**
Now when I perform the following command, I get this error -

```
mac-machine:project-mars john$ go build main.go 
main.go:5:5: cannot find package "helper" in any of:
    /Users/john/apps/go/src/helper (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/john/apps/go-packages/src/helper (from $GOPATH)
```

I understand that GOPATH should be the project directory that I am working on. But I am concerned with keeping my projects and library packages in a modular way, so that when later I have a totally different project (i.e. project-aurora) which might use same github helper packages, that they are not downloaded two times, both in project-mars and project-aurora .

How can I avoid this redundancy while working on different projects ?

**Update:** It's not that I can not compile them. I can use the GOPATH as my project directory and use src,pkg,bin project layouts and also reorganize the files and finally get to compile the project. yeeeeppi. But my question is about resolving the redundancy of common package problem that appears in this single GOPATH way.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) carefully. It explains everything you need to know.

You don't use `GOPATH` as your project directory. Assuming you want to work with the standard Go tooling, your package source needs to be in the directory corresponding to its import path, just like any other package.

Your project should be located at `$GOPATH/src/project-mars`, which can be built via `go install project-mars`. The `helper` package should be located at `$GOPATH/src/project-mars/helper`, and imported via `"project-mars/helper"`.

Comment: Thanks JimB. I read the full article. Nicely put. My concern was if I have projects that can be in totally separate locations irrespective of `GOPATH`, how does go handle that? I assume go is designed to force the developers to keep all the go codes in `GOPATH/src` directory. Is this correct? If it's correct, that means, keeping project directories in different location ( i.e. `/Users/john/hobist-projects/project-mars`, `/Users/john/hobist-projects/project-samurai` and `/Users/john/office-projects/projects-aurora` ) is really bad. I am curious about the reason of go marking it as a bad design.

Comment: @imranhasanhira: the Go tools work by convention, rather than configuration. Having one way to do things makes it simpler, and everyone can collaborate in the same way. If you want to structure your projects differently, you're free to do what you want, but you should know how the tools work in the first place and what to expect from them. You are also free to use other build tools, like [gb](https://getgb.io/) for example, which allows a "project based workflow".

Answer (score 0):

Rename your *helper-lib* folder to *helper*

Then move this folder from *project-mars* to the upper folder *work*

This should make your

```
import "helper"
```

statement in main.go work.

Comment: BTW, The GOPATH shall be changed to GOPATH = /Users/john/work/

Comment: Renaming the directory to "helper" from "helper-lib" makes sense. 

But moving "helper" directory one above "project-mars" seems unlikely, because in that way, **helper** directory would be sibling of **project-mars** and **project-aurora** . Actually I used subdirectories to package my codes. For example when I would have a lot more files, putting them outside project base directory would loose the modularity.

Also GOPATH is set to a separate location, according to the need I expected to have for reusing common libraries across projects.

Comment: Thanks Zee for pointing out the "helper-lib" directory name. I will update it in my question to get the focus on the problem that I wanted to torch on.

Comment: My understanding is you want this helper package be shared with multiple projects. In this case. Putting this folder under your project folder means it is not shared with other project

Comment: If you really want your package folder in Mars. Change the import statement to import "project-mars/helper"

Comment: Sorry for abrupt name. **helper** is **project-mars** related helper files. So they should remain inside **project-mars** directory. And changing the import path won't help, because you can see that the compilation error was based on the GOROOT and GOPATH locations ( which might be completely different than **project-mars** ) . If this kind of modularity is not possible in the I am expecting, then either I am doing it wrong, or there must be some good project layout which doesn't introduce this redundancy.